# vuejs v-model - TypeError: Cannot read property '_wrapper' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm getting TypeError: Cannot read property '_wrapper' of undefined error when i using v-model.

here is my code sample,

```html
 <b-form-input v-model="send_mail.recipients" 
                                                  type="text"
                                                  placeholder="Type email"
                                                  trim>
 </b-form-input>
```

it's a simple model bind nothing else. also created the variables.
when type in the text area it's getting this error. anyone had this error before?

Comment: please share more code

Comment: Ok let me update.